# Помогите написать частотный анализ текста на Pascal

Tags: pascal

Провести частотный анализ текста. Построить столбиковую гистограмму, отражающую количество слов в тексте, начинающихся на буквы заданного алфавита.

Comment: @VeFox, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

> количество слов в тексте, начинающихся на буквы заданного алфавита

Равносильно количеству букв, встречающихся на первых позициях слов. Следовательно задача сводится к подсчету первых букв. Каждой латинской букве соответствует ASCII код символа. Поэтому в таким случаях используют обыкновенный массив целых чисел, где индексом будет являться ASCII код символа, а значением - количество таких символов в тексте. Вам нужно смотреть только символы после whitespace (пробел, табуляция, перенос строки, перенос каретки), так как нужны только первые буквы. Также следует приводить их все либо к строчной, либо к заглавной, так как буква одна и та же, а ASCII коды у них разные.
Выводить гистограмму будем символами '#'. При построении гистограммы важно чтобы была верхняя граница, то есть если какой-то символ встречается 90 раз, чтобы в гистограмме не было 90 символов '#', а например, 30. Для этого нужно перевести в проценты каждое число встретившихся символов. Тут применяется школьная математика. Далее проходим по нашему массиву, N раз, где N - макс. высота гистограммы, выводим символы '#', если процентное значение достигло данной высоты, иначе ' '.

В остальном же,
согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: я могу построить гистограмму, но, к сожалению, чтобы ее построить нужно знать количество этих самых слов, которые начинаются на заданные буквы, а как посчитать эти слова, я не знаю.
не могли бы вы мне подсказать, с помощью какой операции мне можно "идти" по строке

Comment: В паскале есть тип string, также есть функция readln. Идти по строке обычным циклом.

Comment: Началом слова может быть и символ стоящий после кавычек `"`